# How to find out the ratio of negative numbers in huge dataset

Tags: java

I am trying to print negative numbers but it is saying that ArrayList cannot be resolved

```
Boolean breaking = false;
for (int row = 0; row < ArrayList.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < ArrayList[row].length; col++) {
        if (ArrayList[row][col] < 0) {
            //Number is negative
            breaking = true; // Variable to break out of outer loop
            break;

        }
    }  //inner for loop scope ends here
    if (breaking) {
        break;
    }
```

Comment: `ArrayList` is already a class name in Java, this is a bad idea to call an array like that.

Comment: Well, where is the ArrayList variable declared and initialized? Please respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lowercase letter. Don't use a `Boolean` when you could use a `boolean`.

Comment: so what do u suggest to do?

Comment: To show us where the ArrayList variable is declared.

Comment: "cannot be resolved" sounds like you didn’t declare the array variable. In Java all variables need to be declared.
If you need the ratio, I suggest you count the negatives (without breaking out of the loop) and the total, then divide in the end. You will probably want to convert the counts to type double before dividing.
On the other hand, if you really want to break out of the outer loop from within the inner loop, you may use a label.

Comment: I'd say the first thing you should do is change the variable name of that array.

Comment: @JB Nizet                                                                                              public static ArrayList<Act2010> dataArrayList = new ArrayList<Act2010>();

Comment: So, your variable is named `dataArrayList`. Not `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` is the **type** of the variable, not its name. But ArrayList doesn't have any `length` attribute, and can't be accessed like a 2D array. This doesn't make much sense. If you need a 2D array of integers, then the variable should be of type `int[][]`, not of type `ArrayList<Act2010>`.

Comment: I got it... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all, java is a case sensitive language, that means that `boolean` and `Boolean` are different things. `boolean` is a primitive type when `Boolean` is an object. don't use `Boolean` if you don't really need to.

`ArrayList` is also a class in java, and using this word can cause you troubles. Don't use saved words or class names for variables. Change your array's name.

Comment: I understood.. Thanks